# How to group by two fields using bash scripting?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Here is one example of one line of log:

```
2016-04-24 23:59:45 -1  6bd3fbb8-65ac-4d16-bf32-48659a76c499    2           +15173583107    14      +161760555935   14      de.xxxx-O2  layxxxd 0   1
```

I know how to group by one filed, so this is the solution:

```
awk '{arr[$11]+=$12} END {for (i in arr) {print i,arr[i]}}' exmaple.log
```

and this would be results:

```
xx 144
layxxxd 49.267
```

My question is that how can I group by two fields instead of one, first should be `$11` and second is `$10`? So results should change to:

```
layxxxd unknown 100
layxxxd de.xxxx-O2 44
```

Comment: try something like this: `awk '{arr[$11 $12]+=$12} END {for (i in arr) {print i,arr[i]}}' exmaple.log`

Comment: @ritesht93 no, never do `arr[$11 $12]...` as it turns different combinations of the fields into the same index string. e.g. $11="a" and $12="bc" would create the same array index "abc" as $11="ab" and $12="c" would. See [@anubhava's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36885254/1745001) for one valid approach.

Comment: @EdMorton Oh yeah thanks.. That's a valid point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I group by two fields instead of one, first should be `$11` and second is `$10`?

You can use `$11 FS $10` as your key for associative array:

```
awk '{arr[$11 FS $10] += $12} END {for (i in arr) {print i,arr[i]}}' exmaple.log
```